# Connecting a php/nginx docker container to external mysql

Tags: docker

As the title says, I am trying to connect php/nginx container to mysql (xampp). Which is the best way to do this? I couldn't find anything online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
**DB_HOST=host.docker.internal**
DB_PORT=3306
```

I solved it by using host.docker.internal as DB_HOST, it automatically translates to the host IP.